# [okhttp]:check permission begin! [okhttp]:not mms! [okhttp]:not email

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-volley

I am getting this error while using volly library in my android studio projecte while running the app in my emulator and real deivce ! How can i resolve this!

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming because you had forgotten to connect your emulator / mobile device to the internet. Make Sure that your Internet or Wifi will be enabled! Because this type of library like volley needs internet Connection.

REASONS:-

- Your Mobile / Emulator is not connected to the Internet
- You had not been given Internet and Network state Permission in the Android
  Manifest File :

  Paste the below code in the android manifest file.

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

NOTE:- This tag should be placed BEFORE the application TAG. If you put if after application TAG, it produces a warning.

**MANIFEST FILE AFTER ADDING CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="app.com.example.android.sunshine" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks!